# Access VBA: get the last row of an Excel sheet

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

With Access VBA, I am getting some data from an Excel file to move to an Access table.

I get

> Application-defined or Object-defined error

on this code line:

```
For Each c1 In mSheet.Range(mSheet.Range("F4"), mSheet.Range("F4").End(xlDown)).Cells
```

The issue is surely due to `.End(xlDown)`: I have tried to remove `.End(xlDown)` and it works.

As an alternative, I used this other code but nothing changed:

```
Dim mRow As Integer
mRow = mSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
```

In this case, I get

> Error 1004: Unable to get the SpecialCells property of the Range
>   class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a reference set to the Excel object library, `xlDown` has no value. Add:

```
Const xlDown as Long = -4121
```

to your code. Though generally it is better to work up from the bottom of the sheet.